# How to add multiple rowsources to a MSForms listbox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, range

been trying to set multiple ranges to a listbox, while filtering my sheet.

I tried this one, but it gives me a runtime error.

```
ListBox1.RowSource = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F1,A15:F15").Address
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

Edit: I could run this without error

```
ListBox1.RowSource = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F1", "A15:F15").Address
```

But it fills the list with Row 1 **until** 15, not only 1 and 15...

Comment: What kind of list box do you use? Is it a sheet Form or ActiveX type? Is it a form control?

Comment: It is a MSForms.ListBox in UserForms

Comment: OK. I will pot an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set a discontinuous range as a list box `RowSource`, but you can use a trick. I mean to create an array then fill it with the discontinuous range areas and load the list box using its `List` property.

Please, copy the next code in the `UserForm_Initialize` event and show the form:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Dim arr, rng As Range, sh As Worksheet, K As Long
  Dim aRng As Range, C As Range
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  Set rng = sh.Range("A1:F1,A3:F3")
  
  ReDim arr(1 To rng.cells.count)
  For Each aRng In rng.Areas
    For Each C In aRng
        K = K + 1: arr(K) = C.Value
    Next
  Next
  Me.ListBox1.list = Application.Transpose(arr)
End Sub
```

The above solution works to load the array with one single column containing all cells in the discontinuous range.

In order to fill the array with as many columns are in the two ranges (6) and two rows, I will prepare another piece of code and post in some minutes.

Please, test the next code (copied inside `Initialeze` event):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, aArr, fArr, combinedArr
  Set sh = ActiveSheet

  With Application
      aArr = .Index(Range("A1:F1").Value, 1, 0)
      fArr = .Index(Range("A3:F3").Value, 1, 0)
      combinedArr = .Transpose(Array(aArr, fArr))
  End With

  With Me.ListBox1
    .Clear
    .ColumnCount = 6
    .list = Application.Transpose(combinedArr)
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately doesnt work well... with Range("A1:F1,A3:F3") I get a runtime error. With Range("A1:F1", "A3:F3") I get a listItem per cell, but I need an entry per row with x cols...

Comment: @Frbr: I do not understand anything from your comment... What does/doesn't it? Did you see the second variant of my answer? What do you need accomplishing? To load all the values of the discontinuous range on a list box column, or to load it on 6 columns and tow rows? My above code presents solutions for both cases. Do you need something else? If yes, you should accurately describe what you want accomplishing...

Comment: Second code works, very thanks !!! :) Saw the second answer after I commented.

Comment: @Frbr: Glad I could help! But your question was not clear regarding the way to load the list box... That's why I tried solving both logical situations... And `Range("A1:F1", "A3:F3")` has no any meaning in VBA. That's why the error.

Comment: I know, my first question and in mind, you all know what I want :D Next time more infos!